# Can someone explain this function?

Tags: javascript

How does the spawn function work?

```
var max_bollar = 15;
var i = 0;
var timecounter = 0;
var bollarcounter = 0;
var spawn_delay = 5;
var min_spawn_delay = 25;
var max_spawn_delay = 500;
var balls = [];

function spawn(i)
{
    var boll = {x: random(totalWidth), y: 0};
    circle(boll.x, 0, 10, "blue");
    timecounter = 0;
    bollarcounter++;
    max_spawn_delay = (random(max_spawn_delay - min_spawn_delay) + min_spawn_delay);
    balls.push(boll);
}

function update()
{
    fill("black");
    timecounter += 1;
    if(timecounter == spawn_delay && bollarcounter < max_bollar)
    {
         spawn(bollarcounter);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        balls[i].y += 10;
        circle(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, 10, "blue");
    }
}
```

So what i don't get is the

```
spawn(bollarcounter);
```

If i have understod functions right the i in

```
function spawn(i)
```

should be replaysed with the bollarcounter but there is no i in the spawn function so why when i want to spawn the balls use

```
spawn(bollarcounter);
```

?

Comment: Maybe you can give some more details about what you're not clear on? Further context about how you want to use it would be helpful as well. Please edit your question to include this information (a more informative title would be good while you're at it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we are unsure what the game or rendering library is, I have commented the code to tell what I think it does. It appears to make rain drops.

```
var max_bollar = 15; // Lots of setup - should be explanatory. Skip to update()
var i = 0;
var timecounter = 0;
var bollarcounter = 0;
var spawn_delay = 5;
var min_spawn_delay = 25;
var max_spawn_delay = 500;
var balls = [];

function spawn(i)
{
    var boll = {x: random(totalWidth), y: 0}; // spawns boll at y:0 and randomly along the x
    circle(boll.x, 0, 10, "blue"); // draws boll at coords, 10 radius/diameter filled blue
    timecounter = 0; // resets time counter (should be in update)
    bollarcounter++; // increases boll count
    max_spawn_delay = (random(max_spawn_delay - min_spawn_delay) + min_spawn_delay); // makes random delay between min and max delay - OVERWRITING the max delay value
    balls.push(boll); // adds boll to balls list
}

function update()
{
    fill("black"); // Fills canvas with black
    timecounter += 1; // Increments tick counter
    if(timecounter == spawn_delay && bollarcounter < max_bollar)
    // If we have less that 15 boll and tick counter is at 5 - run the below
    {
         spawn(bollarcounter); // spawn boll
         // SHOULD reset time counter to 0, else we will never spawn another
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        // iterates through the bolls
        balls[i].y += 10; // moves the currently selected boll 10 (px down)
        circle(balls[i].x, balls[i].y, 10, "blue"); // redraws boll with 10 radius/diameter and colored blue
    }
}
```